# CSV how to trim values to 2 places in multiple columns using UNIX

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

The sample file structure is given below

```
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.999999,1.409999,15.9988999
Biscuit,2.999999,2.409999,15.9988999
```

The output file is expected to be in the format below:

```
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.99,1.40,15.99
Biscuit,2.99,2.40,15.99
```

Comment: Do you really mean UNIX or are you running Linux? If UNIX, do you have access to GNU tools?

Answer (score 9):

On systems with GNU Coreutils, you might consider using `numfmt` e.g.

```
$ numfmt --delimiter=, --header --field=2- --format='%.2f' --round=down < file.csv 
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.99,1.40,15.99
Biscuit,2.99,2.40,15.99
```

If you want conventional IEEE from-zero rounding, omit the `--round=down` directive.

Answer (score 5):

This does what you asked for:

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]*/\1/g' file.csv 
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.99,1.40,15.99
Biscuit,2.99,2.40,15.99
```

Or, if you want to round the numbers instead of just removing the extra digits, you could try:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf("%0.2f",$1)/ge' file.csv 
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,2.00,1.41,16.00
Biscuit,3.00,2.41,16.00
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -F "," 'NR>1{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' y.txt |awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,4),substr($3,1,4),substr($4,1,5)}'|awk 'OFS="," {print $1,$2,$3,$4}1' filename

Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.99,1.40,15.99
Biscuit,2.99,2.40,15.99
```

Comment: I'd advise caution here, as it assumes that the numbers will always be the same scale (as it hard-codes the substring length to prune).

Comment: This seems overly complicated, not to mention that the last `awk` is given an input file and ignores the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to truncate the numeric values to two decimals:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in $*) { is_numeric(v) { $[k] = fmtnum(floor(v*100)/100,"%.2f") } }' file
Product,Base_Price,Promotion_Price,Discount
Shampoo,1.99,1.40,15.99
Biscuit,2.99,2.40,15.99
```